# Find a continuous function with the following properties:

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

**Part A:** Let $H = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \; \rvert \; \text{Re}(z) \geq 0\} \setminus\{0\}$. Specifying any branch cuts you may use, find a continuous function $f:H \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

1. $f$ is harmonic in $H$.
2. $f(z)=1$ on the positive imaginary axis.
3. $f(z) = 0$ on the negative imaginary axis.

**Part B:** Let $D = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \; \rvert \; |z| \leq 1\} \setminus\{-1,1\}$. Specifying any branch cuts you may use, find a continuous function $g:D \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

1. $g$ is harmonic in $D$.
2. $g(z)=1$ for $|z|=1$, $\text{Im}(z)>0$.
3. $g(z)=1$ for $|z|=1$, $\text{Im}(z)<0$.

**My attempt:**

*For part A:* Using the principal branch of the logarithm, i.e. not allowing $(-\infty,0]$, we have that $\text{Log}(z) = \ln|z| + i\text{Arg}(z)$ is analytic, hence its real and imaginary parts are harmonic. Thus $\text{Arg}(z)$ is harmonic. To get properties 2 and 3, I'll just define $f$ as the following:

$$ f(z) = \frac{\text{Arg}(z) + \pi/2}{\pi}$$

*For part B:* I am not sure. I found a solution for part A reasoning through it intuitively, but I can't seem to find anything for part B this way. I'm wondering if there is a better technique for solving problems like this that I'm just unaware of.

Comment: Hint: Consider the conformal mapping $z \mapsto \frac{2}{z + 1} - 1$ from $D$ to $H$.

Comment: *Hint:* Find a conformal map from the unit disk to the right halfplane.